Checking associativity in the proof of Theorem 3.2 (Rotman, Introduction to Algebraic Topology)
Theorem 3.2. If $X$ is a space, then the set of all path classes in $X$ under the (not always defined) binary operation $[f][g] = [f * g]$ forms an algebraic system (called a $\textbf{groupoid}$) satisfying the following properties:
ii) Associativity holds whenever possible
(Of course, there are more parts to the problem, but this is what I'm trying to verify).
Here's Rotman's proof for that part:
To prove associativity, use the picture below:

First, draw the slanted lines in $\textbf{I} \times \textbf{I}$ and write their equations. On each of the three pieces, construct a continuous function whose formula is, for each fixed $t$, the affine map from the bottom 0th interval (e.g., from $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$) to the upper $t$th interval (e.g., to $[0, (2 - t)/4]$). It suffices to show that the continuous map obtained by gluing maps together, as in part (i), is a homotopy $f * (g * h) \simeq (f * g) * h \text{ rel } \overset{*}{\textbf{I}}$, and this is routine.
Here's my attempt at constructing such a homotopy:
For each $t \in \textbf{I}$, let $\theta_t: [0, \frac{1}{2}] \to [0, \frac{2 - t}{4}]$, $\gamma_t: [\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}] \to [\frac{2 - t}{4}, \frac{3 - t}{4}]$, $\alpha_t: [\frac{3}{4}, 1] \to [\frac{3 - t}{4}, 1]$ be the affine maps matching the endpoints of these intervals. Define $H: \textbf{I} \times \textbf{I} \to X$ by
$$H(s, t) = 
\begin{cases}
f\bigl(\theta_t(s)\bigl) \text{ if } t \leq -4s + 2 \\
g\bigl(\gamma_t(s)\bigl) \text{ if } -4s + 2 \leq t \leq -4s + 3 \\
h\bigl(\alpha_t(s)\bigl) \text{ if } t \geq -4s + 3 \\
\end{cases}$$
However, this seems to be incorrect, for if $0 \leq s \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then $H(s, 0) = f\bigl(\theta_0(s)\bigl) = f(s) \neq f(2s) = \bigl(f * (g * h)\bigl)(s)$. Can somebody point me to my error? Thank you.

Fairly certain $f * (g * h)$ should give $\begin{cases} f(2(t-0)) ,& t \in [0,1/2]  \
g(4(t - 1/2)) ,& t \in [1/2,3/4]  \ h(4(t-3/4)) ,& t \in [3/4,1] \end{cases}$, where in each line we have $F\left(\frac{1}{w}(t-\ell)\right) , t \in [\ell, \ell + w]$ where $F$ is the function for the path component on that $t$-interval.

At level $t$ of the desired homotopy we have to rescale $f$ to the interval $[0,\frac{2-t}{4}]$ via the affine map $\theta_t : [0,\frac{2-t}{4}] \to [0,1]$, $g$ to the interval $[\frac{2-t}{4},\frac{3-t}{4}]$ via the affine map $\gamma_t : [\frac{2-t}{4},\frac{3-t}{4}] \to [0,1]$ and $h$ to the interval $[\frac{3-t}{4},1]$ via the affine map $\alpha_t : [\frac{3-t}{4},1] \to [0,1]$. This produces
$$H(s,t) = \begin{cases} f(\theta_t(s)) & 0 \le s \le \frac{2-t}{4} \\  g(\gamma_t(s)) & \frac{2-t}{4} \le s \le \frac{3-t}{4} \\ h(\alpha_t(s)) & \frac{3-t}{4} \le s \le 1 \end{cases} $$
Another method to prove associativity is this:
Let $u : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ map $[0, \frac 1 2]$ affinely to $[0,\frac 1 4]$, $[\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4]$ affinely to $[\frac 1 4, \frac 1 2]$ and $[\frac 3 4, 1]$ affinely to $[\frac 1 2, 1]$. Then $f *( g * h) = \big((f * g) * h\big) \circ u$. But clearly $u$ is homotopic rel. $\{0,1\}$ to the identity (as a homotopy take $\phi(s,t) = (1-t)u(s) + ts$), hence
$$(f*g)*h \simeq \big((f * g) * h\big) \circ u = f*(g* h) \text{ rel.} \{0,1\} .$$

Thank you for the response? Would you mind explaining why we have to rescale each of the components via the affine maps to $[0, 1]$?

$f$ is defined on the full interval $[0,1]$, thus at homotopy level $t$ the subinterval $I_{f,t} = [0,\frac{2-t}{4}]$ has to be mapped affinely onto $[0,1]$ in order that on $I_{f,t}$ we traverse the path described by $f$. For $g$ and $h$ analogously.

That helps a lot! Thanks for explaining and your help.

If you like the answer, you should take into consideration to accept it. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. This clears it from the "unanswered queue" (https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

By the way, I think it is not really clear what Rotman wants to say in the paragraph beginning with "First, draw ...".  Probably he intended to apply the "other method" in my answer. Gluing the maps $\theta_t, \gamma_t,\alpha_t$ as defined in your question produces a map $\phi_t : [0,1] \to [0,1]$. The $\phi_t$ give a homotopy $\phi$ as in my answer. But then $\big((f*g)*h\big)\circ \phi$ is the desired homotopy. You can check that it agrees with $H$ in my answer.
